# PyQt: Move an image around a canvas and save canvas image as PNG

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, qimage

I am a beginner in PyQt and I am trying to create a canvas where I could place multiple PNG images and move it around the canvas. (Pretty much like the Photoshop/GIMP). May I have any pointers on how to realize these?

- Dragging actual image from the list to place on canvas
- Move images around the canvas
- Save the whole canvas (including the images placed on the canvas) as a single PNG file with transparent background

Here is a diagram illustrating what I am trying to achieve: the green arrows are the drag actions and the images are free to move around the canvas upon selection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmnB5.png

I have tried to create the image list but I am not sure how to drag the image out. I would also like to know the correct way of implementating a canvas which allow image to place on it. I have tried `QPainter` but it seems irrelevant to the task i am trying to achieve.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageQt

class DragDropListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(72, 72))
        print(self.size())
        print(self.sizeHint())
        self.resize(self.sizeHint())

        folder_path = 'dummy_folder'
        list_files = self.get_img_list(folder_path)
        for file in list_files:
            in_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
            self.put_into_img_list(in_path)

    def put_into_img_list(self, path):
        picture = Image.open(path)
        picture.thumbnail((71, 71), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        icon = QIcon(QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt.ImageQt(picture)))
        item = QListWidgetItem(path, self)
        item.setStatusTip(path)
        item.setIcon(icon)

    def get_img_list(self, path):
        IMG_FORMATS = 'png', 'PNG'
        list_img = [img for img in os.listdir(path) if (img.split(".")[-1] in IMG_FORMATS) ==True]
        return list_img

class MyCanvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # creating canvas
        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.black)

# creating class for window
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        title = "Dummy GIMP"
        top = 0
        left = 0
        width = 800
        height = 450
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.canvas = MyCanvas()
        self.image_list = DragDropListWidget()
        wid = QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)
        box.addWidget(self.image_list)
        box.addWidget(QPushButton("Save as PNG"))
        box.addWidget(self.canvas)
        wid.setLayout(box)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Code output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAFbT.png

Comment: what do you mean by "save the canvas as a png file" ? Lets say you have placed 4 pics on your gui, what should happen with them ?

Comment: While it *is* possible to do so with a custom widget, it would become quite difficult and painful to "fix" everytime you need to add some features. Instead, use the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).

Comment: @accpert.com I meant to save the placed 4 pics in the canvas to become 1 png image with transparent background.

Comment: @musicamante Do you mean I could start implementing my canvas with the Graphics View framework or I should reimplement the image list with the framework?

Comment: @MaxKu The canvas. Note that we don't provide "tutorials", "pointers" or "examples", and you're also actually asking 4 very different questions (only *one* question per post can be asked on StackOverflow): 1. drag from list and drop to canvas; 2. implementing the canvas; 3. moving the images; 4. saving the canvas. The first question is too broad (look for tutorials and questions about d'n'd with Qt), while the answer to the other questions can be reduced to "use the Graphics View framework": it provides items that can be movable (including pixmaps) and its scene can be rendered to an image.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the note, will check "Graphics View framework" out.

Comment: @MaxKu You're welcome. Be aware: the graphics view framework is **not** an easy one. It's extremely powerful and has quite good performance even when dealing with thousands of items or extremely large "scenes". But all that has a cost: you have to *understand* it, which can be very demanding. I strongly suggest you to start by playing with it using the basic primitive item types, **carefully studying the documentation** and creating very simple tests on your own in order to really understand how it works. The suggestion is: «be patient to learn».

Comment: Placing four  labels to a frame and droping pics from a list to them is doable. After clicking a button, there could be a procedure that saves the 4 pics to one.